# How to validate input fields in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for the validation of my form in react.

**What I am doing**

1. I have one select dropdown, which has some numbers as a dropdown.
2. On change of select dropdown I am creating the input field, if 2 is selected then 2 input field, initially one is there by default.
3. Now when I select 2 or 3 options and create 2-3 input fields, on click of a button it is only taking last field validation as well as giving me the last field value only.

In `react-hook-form` we use `ref` to hold the value of particular input and for validation as well.

But here it is only validating the last one only, I do not know what I am missing.

This is what I am doing.

```
<div className="row">
  {[...Array(inputHolder).keys()].map((li, index) => (
    <div className="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          id={'name' + index}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="F Name"
          ref={register({required: 'F name is required'})}
        />
        <label className="common_label_form" htmlFor={'name' + index}>
          F Name
        </label>
        {errors.name && (
          <div>
            <span className="text-danger">{errors.name.message}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>;
```

[This my code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-sun-0j65c?file=/src/App.js)

I need to make my `refs` dynamic but I don't know how can I achieve that.

I want to have data like  `[{ name: 'name1' }, { name: 'name2' }]`, that's why I have been stuck, once I will get data then I can push it inside array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `form`, any input elements (`input`, `select`...) inside it is identified via a `name` attribute, not `id` as you may think.

#### Solution 1:

```js
map(_, index) => (
  <input
    name={`name[${index}]`}
    ref={register}
  />
)
```

When you log the submit data, here is what it looks like

```js
{
  "name": ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

**Error displaying:**

```js
{errors.name && errors.name[index] && (
  <div>
    {errors.name[index].message}
  </div>
)}
```

#### Solution 2:

```js
map(_, index) => (
  <input
    name={`data[${index}].name`}
    ref={register}
  />
)
```

**Output**

```js
{
  "data": [
     { "name": "1" },
     { "name": "2" },
     { "name": "3" }
  ]
}
```

**Error displaying**

```js
{errors.data && errors.data[index] && errors.data[index].name && (
  <div>
    {errors.data[index].name.message}
  </div>
)}
```

#### Solution 3:

```js
map(_, index) => (
  <input
    name={`name_${index}`}
    ref={register}
  />
)
```

**Output:**

```js
{
  "name_0": "1",
  "name_1": "2",
  "name_2": "3"
}
```

**Error displaying:**

```js
{errors["name_" + index] && (
  <div>
    {errors["name_" + index].message}
  </div>
)}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64219677/how-to-validate-input-fields-in-react]

Comment: hey could you please check out this issue, it is something similar to above one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241134/how-to-validate-multistep-form-in-react  please check what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud simply change the input `name` li ke this

```js
...
        <input
          type="text"
          name={'name' + index}   // you should change this
          id={'name' + index}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="F Name"
          ref={register({required: 'F name is required'})}
        />
...
```

Comment: I tried this but this will cause issue,I need to send data in some format, that can cause issue

Comment: what kind of issue ?

Comment: first of all, I am not able to do validation by using the above approach you have shared, please check my code sandbox, to handle error I am doing like this errors.name but now as I am concatenating index, so it is throwing error errors.name+index this throws error, if this is done then also I have issue and this is main one, I have to send data like this [{ name: 'name1' }, { name: 'name1' }].. so what you are suggesting will not work for me

Comment: i extend your codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-edison-fk7qs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark